# css background issue when running the app on ipad phonegap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am trying to develop an application via phonegap and there is a very strange issue.

I have a bootstrap modal on click of an option or virtual keypad of Ipad. The background overlaps my modal as the modal opens up.
Any solution?

```
    if (navigator.platform == 'iPad') {
    $(".ipadissue").css("position", "absolute");
    $('.ipadissue').css('top', window.innerHeight + window.scrollY - 130 + "px");}
$(".modal").live("click", function() {
    if ($(this).attr('aria-hidden') == "false")
    {
        $("#content").css("position", "fixed");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#content").css("position", "absolute");
        $("#modal-content").css("position", "absolute");
    }
});

if (navigator.platform == 'iPad') {
$(function() {

    $(document).on('focusin', 'input, textarea', function() {
        $('#header').css("position", "absolute");
        $('.searchbardiv').css("position", "absolute");
    })
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type=file], a', function() {
        $('#header').css("position", "absolute");
        $('.searchbardiv').css("position", "absolute");

    })
    $("input[type=file]").on('change', function() {
        $('#header').css("position", "absolute");
        $('.searchbardiv').css("position", "absolute");
    })
            .on('focusout', 'input, textarea', function() {
        $('#header').css("position", "fixed");
        $('.searchbardiv').css("position", "fixed");
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Some of your relevant CSS code would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Without the respective coe, how do you expect the community to resolve your issue..??